# Return value from helper file to another file

Tags: swift

I have a helper file and I am getting the correct values from the function, which is an extension.

```
extension IAPHelper: SKProductsRequestDelegate
{

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse)
    {

        self.products = response.products

        for product in response.products
        {

            print(product.price) 

        }

    }


}
```

I have an another ViewController, in which there is a table cell. I want to pass this price to that cell. How can I do it?

Comment: you can use `completion handler` or `delegate` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple ways to achieve this, but `completion handler` is the way i prefer most.

create a `var completionHandler` in your `IAPHelper` class, and perform its work after getting your values:

Declare completionHandler in your calls as below:

```
var completionHandler: (([NSNumber])->Void)?
```

You can use this in your `SKProductsRequestDelegate` method of `IAPHelper` to perform:

```
var prices :[NSNumber] = []
for product in response.products
{
    print(product.price) 
    prices.append(product.price)
}
if let handler = completionHandler {
   handler(prices)
}
```

To get values in your another ViewController or any other class just do:

```
   let helper = IAPHelper()
    helper.completionHandler = {
        (val:[NSNumber] ) in
            print(val)
    }
```

Comment: I have to return this value to a button inside a table cell. Can you guide me how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

In ViewController contains tableView

```
for product in response.products {
self.items.append(product.price)
}
tableView.reloadData()
```